# sed does not replace a string in a file as expected

Tags: sed

I want to make replace a string in a file `mytest.properties` but it is not getting replaced.

I want to replace `JaWov5Svh/GKAkk8siezbg==` and use the command

```
$ sed -i -- 's/JaWov5Svh/GKAkk8siezbg==/abjhdgetsjsu/d' mytest.properties
```

but the string does not get replaced as expected.

Comment: What is the intended purpose of the `abjhdgetsjsu/d`?

Comment: you have / in your string. need to either escape it or use a different divider char for s. try s#originalstring#replacement#

Comment: put your command in code area and please do some search before posting your question here.

Answer (score 2):

You have a `/` in the text you are trying to replace, but you are also using `/` as a sed "divider".

Try the following instead:

```
sed -i 's@JaWov5Svh/GKAkk8siezbg==@abjhdgetsjsu@' mytest.properties
```